# How can i get rid of unnesesary information from a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe thats made up of 200 rows and 4 columns of banking info.
the rows are 'Date', 'point of sale' 'debit' and 'credit'. in the point of sale column there is a whole bunch of extra information which I do not need and I wan to get rid of. every row starts with 'Point of sale-interac retail purchase.....' which I want to get rid of completely to just have the name of the store instead. I cant seem to figure out how to do this. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Is the string "Point of sale-interac retail purchase" the same every time?

Answer (score 0):

If the string is the same every time, this is pretty easy:

```
replace_string = {'Point of sale-interac retail purchase':''}
df['point of sale'].replace(replace_string, inplace=True)
```